# Is there a windows keyboard layout that would both be QWERTY and allow for french accents without disturbing code

Tags: windows, keyboard, french, qwerty

I'm currently using a Thinkpad on windows using the **US International layout**, meaning it's a QWERTY layout that will deadkey " ' ";  " " "; "`"; and other keystrokes as accents so that **if you press " ' " and then " e ", the resulting character will be an " é "**, but **if you want to just type an apostrophe, then you have to press " ' " and then SPACE.**

Since I have to write a lot of French but also have to use the same computer to do programming, you can understand the hassle of having to switch Keyboard layouts all the time or having to deal with pressing the spacebar after any ' or ".
So would there be a keyboard layout for Windows that would be exactly like QWERTY US but that would allow to put accents by pressing ALT + "accent" and then the letter to apply it to instead of just pressing the accent and the letter which by itself makes apostrophes and doublequotes more troublesome.

**For example if I wanted an " à " I would press AltGr + " ` " and then " a ".**

Hopefully someone has a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had not found a Keyboard layout that would fit my needs I created one using the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.

This layout features the **regular QWERTY layout** plus it adds **all of the accent combinations of QWERTY International with the characters (" ' ` ~ ^) if you hold AltGr in** and I've also added those symbols using AltGr: ° and € as well as most of the Greek alphabet for use in Math: "ωɛρθɣʊɩΩπɑΣΔɸχσ".

Link contains the source file for MKLC if you need to change/add keys as well as the installer for this newly made layout.

You can download this layout [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HcC916QIVFSc-2c0E_ZIhf3YenakQiG3)

Hopefully this will be useful to other users!